# Japanese character are saved as question mark in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, collation

I'm working on SQL Server 2005, in which I have a database. When I use Japanese Characters in my application, they are stored as question marks in the databse. I would like to which Collations should I use save the japanese characters properly.

Note: Additional info(if it helps) In MySQL, we have used UTF8 as default character set in the startup variable and it works file.

Thank you,

Pavan

Comment: What is your app? What language / OS?? Are your SQL Server fields of type `NVARCHAR` ? (that's the 2-byte-per-char Unicode storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Japanese_90 appears to be the new collation name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#intlftrql2005_topic24

Note, you might want to consider the _KS suffix if you want to consider Hirigana/Katakana whilst sorting.
Like Marc_S says, you will also want to ensure your column datatype is nvarchar